# PDO how to tell that a record was deleted?

Tags: php, pdo

I need that after an error deleting a record from the database, redirection to the error page is triggered. When sending a `null` or `zero` value of `$ordernum`, I am still redirected to the `"OK"` page instead of `"ERROR"`. What could be the problem?

The value of the `$ordernum` variable is now set to `null` to simulate a deletion error.:

```
$ordernum = null; //ordernum for test
$redirsuc = "activeorders?out&ordernum=$ordernum&fulldelete=OK";
$redirerr = "activeorders?out&ordernum=$ordernum&fulldelete=ERROR";

$con::sql("DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `ordernum` = ?", [$ordernum], $redirsuc, $redirerr);

if (isset($_GET['fulldelete']) && $_GET['fulldelete'] == "OK" && GetSettings('viberbot') == "ON") {

  $icon = '❌ ';
  $msg = "Test mess";
  $url = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/activeorders?out&sessdepo=".$_SESSION['depo'];
  ViberBot($msg,$icon,$url);
}
```

And here is the function itself with `PDOException`:

```
/**
* @param $query
* @param array $args
* @param mixed $redirsuc
* @param mixed $redirerr
* @return array
*/
public static function sql($query, $args = [], $redirsuc, $redirerr)
{
    try {
        self::run($query, $args);
        if (!empty($redirsuc)) {
            header("Location: $redirsuc");
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        if (!empty($redirerr)) {
            header("Location: $redirerr");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you enable the `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` option?

Comment: Why would setting `$ordernum` to `null` cause a deletion error? It's not an error if no rows are found to delete.

Comment: It's a **very bad** idea to redirect in case of error, for too many reasons.